# what does it mean "class X;" on header file?

Tags: c++

the other day I was searching on github and I came across this game named Pioneer, on file pi.h I noticed a lot of "class X;" statements (where X is "Galaxy","Intro", etc.) [here you can see the code](https://github.com/pioneerspacesim/pioneer/blob/master/src/Pi.h). what is it for? and is it good practice? I supossed it has a simple explanation but I could not find anything on the web.

Comment: Those are the declarations of the classes, they will be defined later.

Comment: [Forward declaration](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Forward_declaration)

Answer (score 2):

It is called a *forward declaration* to introduce a type which is being used later on. Without it the compiler doesn't recognize the type and has no clue what to do with it.